# Java Collections - Maps and Sets: put cannot be applied

Tags: java, collections, maps, set

I'm having trouble with some code. I am trying to create a student database. I need to create a set of students that is represented by a course name. The course name is mapped to the set of students. I've tried to write the 'add' method but when I try to .put it into the database I get an error message: put(java.lang.String,java.util.Set) in java.util.Map> cannot be applied to (java.lang.Integer,StudentDatabase.Student). Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

import java.util.*;

public class StudentDatabase {

```
private Map<String, Set<Integer>> database = new TreeMap<String, Set<Integer>>();

private static class Student extends TreeSet<Integer> {
    public int id;

    public Student(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public void add(String courseName, Integer student) {
    /* I've tried to use this way to add to the database and it doesn't work too.
    Set<Integer> studentSet = database.get(courseName);
    if (studentSet == null){
        studentSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    }
    studentSet.add(student);
    database.put(courseName, student);
    */

   Integer idInt = new Integer(idInt);
   if (database.containsKey(idInt)){
       //if the student is a duplicate, that is ok
    }
    else{
        Student info = new Student(idInt);
        database.put(new Integer(idInt), info);
    }
} // end add
```

}

Comment: I just built something almost exactly what you are doing. Add some comments explaining what your set is storing and what you are mapping and I can help. Is this a school project? If so, post a link to the assignment if available.

Comment: the set stores student id numbers. each course is represented as a set of student id numbers. the database must map from course names to id sets.

Comment: I think it is quite simple and I can help you out. But I couldn't get what is idInt in your add method? Please provide some detail about it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right in the error message: `put(java.lang.String,java.util.Set) in java.util.Map> cannot be applied to (java.lang.Integer,StudentDatabase.Student)`.  which type in the second list doesn't match the type in the first list?

Comment: sorry I don't understand... if you could elaborate that would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the parameter types of `Map#put` with your declaration `Map<String, Set<Integer>>`:

```
Student info = new Student(idInt);
Set<Integer> searchMap = database.get(courseName);
if (searchMap == null) {
   searchMap = new HashSet<String>();
}

searchMap.add(new Integer(idInt));
database.put(courseName, searchMap);
```

Comment: im now getting illegal start of type for:searchMap = new HashSet<>();

Comment: is there a way to get around 'variable idInt might not have been initialized'? i tried initializing it to null but it doesn't have any change

Comment: Ok, have updated. Please also read the [tutorial on Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: The variable cannot be already initialized during the time of initialization. Are you sure you don't want to use `student`? It would be less confusing to call it `studentID`.